# SQL-query should return GeoJSON FeatureCollection

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I'm trying to return a GeoJSON FeatureCollection object from a SQL-query with PostgreSQL 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) AS p
 FROM (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) AS features 
 FROM (SELECT 'Feature' AS type, ST_AsGeoJSON("wkb_geometry")::json AS geometry
 FROM "4547cd00-b570-4504-9796-cf2f61dbebe4") AS f) AS fc;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
```

However, if I just run this query:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON("wkb_geometry")::json AS geometry
 FROM "4547cd00-b570-4504-9796-cf2f61dbebe4";
```

It works and print out a nice geometry.
If I ignore the ST_AsGeoJSON it also prints out a result, but not something I can use as a GeoJSON FeatureCollection, as I need the type and coordinates seperated into JSON.

Comment: Ok, noted. I've also tried to add  WHERE ST_IsValid(ST_AsGeoJSON("wkb_geometry")) at my SELECT, but with same error as before.

Comment: Might [this](http://www.zimmi.cz/posts/2015/postgis-case-study-vozejkmap-open-data-part-ii/) be of any help?